# Stretch PyQt QTableWidget cells horizontally to a size that fills the table (Python)

Tags: python, qtablewidget, pyqt6

I generate a QTableWidget in PyQT (Python). This is the result:[image]

as you can see the cells don't fill horizontally the table and a lot of space remains empty. I would like to make the cells stretch to a size that fills the table.
How can this be done?

Comment: `table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)`.

Comment: Thanks, I had some problems because in PyQt6 the stretch mode is under QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeMode.Stretch

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't pay attention to the tag. All Qt enums use the full flag name under PyQt6, as they are not direct members of the class anymore. I know, that's a bit annoying (and excessively verbose, IMHO, since Qt names are already *very* long). Remember that every time you see a flag/enum that doesn't use the full syntax (because it was used in <Qt6 code) such as `class.enum` or `instance.enum`, you can check the base class documentation to get the actual name.